# Trying to help a west coast fan in an east coast world

Tags: software-recommendation, broadcasting

So my friend wants to hear the west coast announcers during the playoffs - while watching the game on tv. Problem is that the tv broadcast is delayed a few seconds. Does anyone know of a work around? I have computers, recorders, att u-verse and an am radio.

I could run the am broadcast through something and delay it to match the game somehow. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

"I have computers, recorders, att u-verse and an am radio"

Then there's nothing you can't accomplish! (-:

Google shows plenty of examples. This was the first hit for "audio delay software free": http://www.fountainware.com/Products/AudioDelay/index.htm